# Anatomy of a C# .NET MVC Controller Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I just installed the free version of the .NET Visual Web Developer 2010 IDE along with version 3 of the ASP.NET MVC framework.  I'm new enough to C#, .NET, ASP.NET's MVC Framework that I'm a little confused by the base controller class that was generated for me, and what's a C# language feature vs. possible syntactic sugar being provided by the framework

```
Namespace MvcApplication1
    Public Class Default1Controller
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        '
        ' GET: /Default1

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Specifically,

1. In the tutorials I've found online, a `:` is used to indicate inheritance, but here it's actually the word `Inherits`.  Does `Inherits` confer any addition context/features, or is it just another way of saying `:`?
2. The generated `Index` method has no return type, or access modifiers.  I was under the impression that these were a required part of the method signature in C#. Is this an incorrect assumption?  If so, what is the default return type?
3. Also related to the `Index` method is the trailing `as ActionResult`, which sort of looks like a return type for the method signature, but is obviously something else.  What does this do?
4. Are the above differences in the language something that C# is providing me, or is this syntax simplification something that the ASP.NET MVC framework is giving me via meta-programming?

Full answers are great, but a pointer towards a tutorial or reference that doesn't assume knowledge of the ASP.NET ecosystem and would get ac experienced programming

Comment: This code is VB. "Inherits" is used in VB for what the colon is used for in C#. You may have accidentally created your project in VB stepping through creating a new solution and project.

Comment: I can understand you are confused. The code you posted is VB.NET. Did you create a VB website by mistake ?

Comment: Your number one issue is that you're looking at a vb.net file, not a c#.net file.

Comment: Scroll down on this page to the "Creating Your First Application" and stare hard at the left nav. It's very subtle. You choose the default language for the solution there. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Comment: this SO question is going to be my all time favorite.. Bless you mate

Comment: Poking at new things while nursing a sunday hangover appears to be the wrong way of doing things.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you selected the wrong language if you wanted to use C#.  You have posted Visual Basic code.

1. Because this is VB code, it is `Inherits`.  The C# equivalent to this is the colon (`:`)
2. Again, this is another VB syntax confusion point.  Here would be the equivalent C# method:

`public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}`

1. `ActionResult` is the return type (or a class that inherits `ActionResult`) that the method will return.
2. Your confusion is rooted from this being the wrong code language.  But yes, if you don't know MVC ins-and-outs even C# source code will confuse you a bit.  I highly...**HIGHLY** recommend you check out the [ASP.NET MVC Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1).  It gave me a great start on learning and understanding the structure of ASP.NET MVC applications and the development behind them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm familiar with C# and MVC3, but was also like WTF is that?

I see what you did: You created a MVC Visual Basic.Net application.

1: no, that's how vb.net does it.

2: it does. ActionResult is its return type. Thats how vb.net does it...

3: see 2